# How do I detect if a sprite is overlapping any background sprite?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

[image: When the horse object goes over the edge of the rectangle I want to rotate the horse and carriage.]I want to detect if an empty gameobject is between a sprite which I've drawn and the camera.

Background objects are tagged "Background" and are in the layer "background".

Currently, the Debug.log statement always says "Does not detect background". I've tried switching the direction of the raycast from back to forward several times and that didn't fix it. The gameobject shooting the ray has a z position of -1, the sprite has a z position of 0. The sprite has a 2D box collider on it.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class RoomMaker : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float speed = 5;
    public float distance = 5;

    public Transform horse;
    public Transform carriage;


    void Update()
    {
        transform.Translate(Vector2.right * speed * Time.deltaTime);

        RaycastHit2D backgroundInfo = Physics2D.Raycast(horse.position, Vector3.forward, distance);
        if (backgroundInfo)
        {
            Debug.Log("DETECTSBACKGROUND");

        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log("Does not detect Background"); 
            //it always displays this one, it never displays the other debug.log

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: When you select the horse in the editor, does a red/green/blue arrow appear pointing in the direction you'd like to raycast? Does one point in the opposite direction? There is not enough information in the question to fully solve the problem - it is impossible to tell which way the horse is facing as far as we can tell from the question.

Comment: Actually - when you say "in front of" - do you mean "between the camera and the subject" or "in the direction the subject is facing"? A screenshot and/or illustration  of what you're trying to achieve would explain a lot

Comment: The horse object has a rotation of (0,0,0). I'm working with 2D. Does the move tool need to create an arrow in a direction in order to raycast that way?

Comment: The horse object is between the sprite and the camera, according to their z axis positions.

Comment: Are you interested in if any part of the horse overlaps any part of the background? - or specifically if the local origin of the horse overlaps any part of the background? Also, how are you determining if a sprite is a background sprite- is the background gameobject tagged a certain way? Are there more than 1 background gameobjects?

Comment: I want to be able to detect what the horse object is above, to ultimately make the horse and carriage spiral around the room spawning tiles randomly. I'm making a procedural generation system.

Comment: The sprite is tagged as background, I tried using if(hit.collider.tag == "Background") but that didn't work, the background sprite is also in a layer named background, detecting the layer hasn't worked.

Comment: When the horse object is not above the background the pair of objects should rotate 90 degrees.  I can't get the horse object to detect things at all.

Comment: The horse object is the child of the carriage.

Comment: Is the sprite tagged `Background` or `background`? Is the layer `background` or `Background`? Capitalization matters... Also, do the background sprites have colliders?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Consider using [Physics2D.OverlapPointAll](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics2D.OverlapPointAll.html) instead of a raycast.

This will require that background sprites have `Collider2D` components on their gameobjects, their gameobjects be tagged `Background` and be on the `background` layer.

I advise having the `background` layer ignore collisions with everything. See the [physics 2d options documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-Physics2DManager.html) for more information on how to do that.

Here's what the code could look like:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class RoomMaker : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float speed = 5;
    public float distance = 5;

    public Transform horse;
    public Transform carriage;


    void FixedUpdate() // otherwise, visual lag can make for inconsistent collision checking.
    {
        transform.Translate(Vector2.right * speed * Time.deltaTime);

        Collider2D[] cols = Physics2D.OverlapPointAll(
                Vector3.Scale(new Vector3(1,1,0), horse.position), // background at z=0 
                LayerMask.GetMask("background")); // ignore non background layer objects


        Collider2D backgroundCol = null;
        for (int i = 0 ; i < cols.Length ; i++) // order of increasing z value
        {
            if (cols[i].tag == "Background") // may be redundant with layer mask
            {
                backgroundCol = cols[i];
                break;
            }
        }


        if (backgroundCol != null)
        {
            Debug.Log("DETECTSBACKGROUND: " + backgroundCol.name);

        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log("Does not detect Background");     
        }

    }
}
```

I tested with this setup:

[image: Test setup]

Comment: It's still saying Does not detect background, I tried moving the horse and carriage to the same z axis position as the sprite, it didn't work.

Comment: @games247 make sure you read the "This will require..." part. Capitalization matters for tags and layers in unity. I'll be able to test this in about 9 hrs.

Comment: Okay just thought of something, What object is your most recent script supposed to be attached to?

Comment: @games247 I added a `Scale` call to make the `OverlapPointAll` position have z=0 same as the background sprite and doing that made it work for me. You may also want to have the script run in `FixedUpdate` and/or have a very small speed so that lag doesn't make the horse skip over meaningful background sprite positions.  It should work attached to the parent of horse transform but you could put the script anywhere and use `horse.transform.parent.Translate(...);`

Comment: Did you make a unity project and get it to work? I wonder if you have something set up differently than me. Can I see a picture of you're inspector and hierarchy? If I can't get it working soon I may just do a different version of procedural generation, since it's not working for me.

Comment: @games247 Yes, I did test it. I just went through and took screenshots of my testing example being set up and being run. "It's not working for me" isn't a helpful description of the unexpected behavior that is occurring.